# Perform subquery as two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have search for the similar question but I haven't found any. There are two **almost** similar question, but the solution is using the JOIN because he/she was asking for different solution, but mine one is different. I have to use sub-query for Expression from the same table with parent query.

Is it possible for me to perform subquery like this?

```
Select summ.* 
from
    (select 
         t.column1 as 'field_1',
         t.column2 as 'field_2',
         (select
              Sum(u.col1) as 'field_3',
              Sum(u.col2) as 'field_4' 
          from 
              table1 u 
          where 
              u.col3 = t.column1) as 'field_3', 'field_4'),
         t.column5 as 'field_5'
     from 
         table1.t) summ
```

I need this because, if I get `field_3` and `field_4` from a separate subquery, SQL Server will take long time to execute the stored procedure.

Currently, the query like this (note that SQL Server needs to subquery twice for `field_3` and `field_4`):

```
Select summ.* 
from
    (select 
         t.column1 as 'field_1',
         t.column2 as 'field_2',
         (select Sum(u.col1) 
          from table1 u 
          where u.col3 = t.column1) as field_3,
         (select Sum(u.col2) 
          from table1 u 
          where u.col3 = t.column1) as field_4,
         t.column5 as 'field_5'
     from 
         table1.t) summ
```

If that possible, or is there any kind of syntax I can use to accomplish the same thing

I have updated the above (expected) and below (my current) query.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and expected results?  Looking at your current query, you appear to be getting `column1`, `column2`, and `column5` for all rows, as well as the sums of `col1` and `col2` for the table as a whole (copied on each row).

Comment: some sample data and expected result will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`

```
select t.column1 as field_1,
       t.column2 as field_2,
       q.field_3,
       q.field_4,
       t.column5 as field_5
from table1 t
outer apply
  (
    select
      SUM(u.col1) field_3,
      SUM(u.col2) field_4
    from  table1 u
    where u.col3 = t.column1
  ) q
```

You can use external parameters in the `APPLY` subquery. The subquery executes for each rows from `table1 t`.

And I think you can use the following variant too

```
SELECT t.column1 as field_1,
       t.column2 as field_2,
       q.field_3,
       q.field_4,
       t.column5 as field_5
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN
  (
      -- calculate field_3 and field_4 for each col3
      select
        col3,
        SUM(col1) field_3,
        SUM(col2) field_4
      from  table1
      group by col3
  ) u
ON u.col3 = t.column1
```

Comment: It seems to be the one I need, But I will try it first.

Comment: @Newbie - I've updated my answer. The condition `u.col3 = t.column1` was added into the subquery.

Comment: Ok, I got value and performance as I expected. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Newbie - Try one more variant. I've just added it into my answer.

Comment: Ok I 'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the window function SUM() OVER () with CASE WHEN .. to perform the conditional sum

```
select  t.column1 as 'field_1',
        t.column2 as 'field_2',
        sum(case when t.col3 > 3 then col1 end) over() as 'field3'  ,
        sum(case when t.col3 > 3 then col2 end) over() as 'field4'  ,
        t.column5 as 'field_5'
from    table1 t
```

also you don't required the derived table `summ` at all

Comment: This is better than my solution.

Comment: I am going to try it, but meanwhile, I would like to know, will this 'sum(...' be executed two time or one time in order to accomplish both field_3 and field_4 result?

Comment: After I test your code, I think it is my mistake give not accurate dummy code. I am updating my Question.

Comment: @Newbie, I don't really see any different in the question

Answer (score 1):

No you can't return more than one column in a scalar sub query.

Instead you will need to leave it as is, or convert it to a join query.  Since your sub queries aren't correlated with the outer query, you can use this:

```
select t.column1 as 'field_1',
       t.column2 as 'field_2',
       u.column3 as 'field_3',
       u.column4 as 'field_4',
       t.column5 as 'field_5'
  from table1 t
 cross join (select SUM(u.col1) as column3 
                  , SUM(u.col2) as column4
               from table1 u
              where u.col3 > 3) u;
```

In this way fields 3 and 4 will be computed once per execution instead of once (or twice) per record, and joined to every other record in table1.

Comment: Now, I'm gonna try this one.

Comment: @Newbie - I don't think it suits you because you can't use external parameters with `JOIN` operations.